# Project dependencies confusion

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, multi-module

I have

```
 project SB (spring boot using gradle) depends upon
     project A (java with maven) that depends upon
     project B (java with maven)
```

In my SB project, I build one large jar for embedded tomcat deployment. I am not sure if this means projects A & B are modules that get built into my singular jar or if I have to manually build their jar files and place into the SB/libs directory for use.  Since I antcipate many changes, I would prefer one singular jar.

Can anyone offer advice on how to structure this project (ideally in IntelliJ) so I can use all three sources?

Comment: How are you building the jar? Using a tool like Maven or Gradle, or using IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I am doing this all via IntelliJ, but will use Gradle for Jenkins and deployment.  In IntelliJ, the two projects are unseen, despite having them as dependencies in the project settings.

Comment: I think maybe you want projects A and B to be modules in your SB project, not separate projects. Or you can have them as separate projects, but you won't be able to edit the code from inside the SB project.

Comment: So what I did was to create SB project.  Then I selected " New | Project from sources" in IntelliJ.  But does this get build all as one jar when i want to deploy?

Comment: Depends on how you configure gradle or IntelliJ.  For details on how to create Jars in IntelliJ see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933883/intellij-idea-puts-junit-tests-in-jar/31936012#31936012