# Intellij IDEA puts junit tests in jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How to tell Intellij IDEA not to include test classes in artifact? I'm working on a lot of projects so it's better if there's a solution like "ignore everything in `project-dir/test` directory", or even better "put in the jar only classes from `project-dir/src`.

Comment: Can we assume you're using Maven?

Comment: In my case Intellij IDEA does not include test classes. Can you be more explicit about your project structure and build tools you are using?

Comment: No, I don't use Maven

Comment: In the root directory of my project there are two folders: src and test.

Comment: Have you marked the folder as a test folder?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes I did

Answer (score 2):

How are you configuring the jar file in IntelliJ IDEA?

If I go to Project Structure (cmd + ; on Mac, ctrl + shift + s on Windows) and select "Artifacts", when I add a new artifact using "From modules with dependencies" it gives me the option of including tests or not:

[image: From modules with dependencies]

If I add a new jar file using "Empty", then I can choose exactly what appears in the jar file:

[image: Add files]

Here I select "Module Output" and this should only add the class files from your module, not the test files (assuming you have your test directory marked as a test directory, and not as a source directory).

If you look to the left of that screenshot, behind the project structure window, you can see that I have production code in src/main/java and test code in src/test/java, and this test code is coloured green - this does not appear in my jar file if I configure it this way.

Comment: I used Add-JAR-Empty. I tried to do it your way and it worked - after deleting all the libraries from jar there weren't test classes in the jar. But how can I do that without adding libraries to the jar (and so without necessity to remove it)?

Comment: Updated my answer with info on how to do this

Comment: I tried this way, test class is still in the jar. I marked test directory, it is green.
And seems like it was my mistake about first option - I tried again and test classes were in the jar.
Maybe it somehow depends on where test directory is - inside `src` directory, or at the same level?

Comment: Shouldn't depend upon where they are - if the tests are in a different location to the production code, and are marked as test and source, they should always be separate. Try doing a full clean rebuild? If you've been changing configurations it's possible you have old test classes in your production code output directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Gradle. Gradle will provide you with jar tasks that will exclude test files, or those that you ignore. Gradle will only package files in the main directory.

src/main/java

src/test/java

I'm assuming you are not using a build system, and have all files in the root folder. Without direction the IDE will not know which files are tests files and include them in the jar.

You need a build system like Ant, Maven or Gradle. I recommend Gradle it will build as an IntelliJ project, and there are many plugins for the IDE.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my decision not to use build tools. I'd like too, but it's impossible in my case

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project-dir/test Mark Directory as ->Test Source root
Right click on all directory inside project-dir/test and Mark Directory as ->excluded

Now build Artifact it will remove test case

Also check in ctrl+alt+shift+s (file-> project structure ) Click on Artifact From left panel-> now on right side screen From output layout remove all junit or test case related jar